# File downloaded larger than original

Tags: python-3.x, cgi

I'm working on a little python3 server and I want to download a sqlite database from this server. But when I tried that, I discovered that the downloaded file is larger than the original : the original file size is 108K, the downloaded file size is 247K. I've tried this many times, and each time I had the same result. I also checked the sum with sha256, which have different results.

Here is my downloader.py file :

```
import cgi
import os

print('Content-Type: application/octet-stream')
print('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Library.db"\n')

db = os.path.realpath('..') + '/Library.db'
with open(db,'rb') as file:
    print(file.read())
```

Thanks in advance !

EDIT :
I tried that :
$ ./downloader > file
file's size is also 247K.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've finally found the solution. The problem (which I didn't see first) was that the server sent plain text to client. Here is one way to send binary data :

```
import cgi
import os
import shutil
import sys

print('Content-Type: application/octet-stream; file="Library.db"')
print('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Library.db"\n')

sys.stdout.flush()
db = os.path.realpath('..') + '/Library.db'
with open(db,'rb') as file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(file, sys.stdout.buffer)
```

But if someone has a better syntax, I would be glad to see it ! Thank you !